# Unable to remove img's attribute with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an HTML string that I want to edit before I send it to the server. The html string has of one or more img elements. In these image elements I would like to remove the `src` attribute, which is a base64 string.

Unfortunately it seems that with the below code it removes the whole image element. Can someone see what I did wrong?

**post.content is the html string. I want to find the image elements inside this string and then for every image change its `src` attribute**

```
// Remove the base 64 src
const $content = $(post.content);
const $img = $content.find('img');
$img.each(function(i) {
    $(this).attr('src', 'dummy');
});
post.content = $content.html();
console.log(post.content);
```

**Result of post.content log when I use the above jQuery**

```
<br>
```

**Result of post.content when I don't use the jquery above, a normal html string and the img with the base64 src**

[image]

**Edit 1: I did a console.log of `$content`, below it is a console.log of `$img` as well**

[image]

Comment: Do `console.log($content.html())` right after setting `$content`.

Comment: I've added it to the original post

Comment: oh sorry, I did it wrong, 2 seconds

Comment: Looks like it’s successfully changing to “dummy” since it’s making a (unsuccessful) call to retrieve it. What would be helpful is if you could boil the code down to a [mcve] (you can use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) to do so).

Comment: The result is just <br> as well.

Comment: Hmm... interesting. What version of jQuery? It looks like it’s only parsing the first node.

Comment: Please edit your question and try to create snippet

Comment: 3.3.1 is the version

Comment: I've recently added jquery. Is it possible that I added the wrong file in angular.json? I added "./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.slim.js" instead of min.js

Comment: In the meantime I'll have a look at creating a snipper

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your `post.content` contains multiple nodes. So when jquery parses it, it will return an array of multiple `<p>` nodes.

Then the last `post.content = $content.html();` will only contains the content of 1st node.

Try to wrap the whole post.content inside a `<div>` like this:

`const $content = $("<div>").html(post.content);`

Check out the full code here: https://jsfiddle.net/vzxq0ckf/1/

Comment: You're a hero. I finally got it to work. Thank you very much man.